# Override method from class to modify method in children

Tags: oop, inheritance, overriding, subclass

`ClassA` has two children :  `ClassB` and `ClassC`.

We need to override a method of `ClassA` but we will be using `ClassB` and `ClassC` (with the modified method).

`ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` are all part of an external library which we can not modify.

Is it possible to get this done without subclassing `ClassB` and `ClassC` seperately using the same re-implementation of the method in each subclass?

*Would the problem be different if `ClassB` already had a re-implementation of the method that we wanted to ignore?*

Comment: Here's a similar question in the specific, somewhat related case, of protocols http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some special mechanism in play that somehow allows you to do this, it is not possible. It would also make no difference if `ClassB` had its own overridden implementation.

Since `ClassB` and `ClassC` have already been compiled, the implementation of their methods has already been baked into your external library. In general, there is nothing you can do at source code level to change this unless you have your own derived classes.

If we are talking about a managed language with a runtime that allows you to dynamically modify the call targets, or if a hot-patching mechanism that can rewrite machine code on the fly is in play then you might have a way out -- but that would be a special exception and not the rule.

Comment: Disappointing, in my particular case this means copy-pasting ~60 lines of source code :(

Answer (score 0):

It sorta depends on the language, and it sounds like a hack at best. If you are writing this in Javascript, you can directly modify the prototype function of class B and C.

In most C-family of languages though, I don't think this is possible. Multiple inheritance may lead to ambiguities (I imagine B and C each have their own subclassing), so you'd probably have to subclass each.